# How to fulfill condition from an enum input?

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-modeler

### The condition that I do not do does not work

`if (@step = '0.5m',"VALUE" like '%.1','')`

---

[image]

Comment: if (0 in @step,"VALUE" like '%.1','') - error. help much needed solution.

Comment: If you have additional information relevant to your question please use the [edit] button beneath it to revise it with that.

Answer (score 4):

When using enum inputs you need to separate between two usecases:

**1. Allow single input:**

Enum returns a single index, which can be interpreted as integer **and** string, such as `0` or `'0'` if the first/top most value is checked. Counting starts at the top of the input-list with index 0.

Your expression in that case would be:

```
if(@enum = 0,'do this if true','do that if false')
```

**2. Allow multiple inputs:**

Enum input returns a list of its indices, starting the count from the top with 0. This list is treated as an already set up array when using expressions, such as `array(0,1,2)` if the first three values are checked, or `array(0)` if only the first/top most value is checked.

Your expression in that case would be:

```
if(array_contains(@enum,0),'do this if true','do that if false')
```

**3. To cover both possible setups:**

You can use a simple `try()` expression, such as:

```
 try(if(@enum=0,'true','false'),if(array_contains(@enum,0),'true','false'))
```

Comment: @Rudzik your true return value does not make any sense (`"VALUE" like '%.1'`). This actually rather looks like another condition. Does it work if you return a simple string or integer instead, like in my example (just to debug the error)?

Comment: Answer is not working. The issue has not been resolved